# Can't connect bootstrap pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to make a basic log in system. I am mixing and matching bootstrap. Signing in layout is done. When I click on sign up, it takes me to another form field and it also works. For some reason when I click on forgot password, it should take me to forgot password page but it does not and nothing happens. I have the "forgotten password" page an ID but whenever I put that ID, the sign in stops working and format messes up.

Here is my code. I added js/css bootstrap code also.

http://jsfiddle.net/8cjrj118/1/

Here is my part of my code for the forgotten password form. I took off the id of "forgotten home" from main page because it was messing everything up.

```
<div style="display: none;" id="form-olvidado">
<h4 class="">
  Forgot your password?
</h4>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="login-recordar" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <span class="help-block">
      Email address you use to log in to your account
      <br>
      We'll send you an email with instructions to choose a new password.
    </span>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        @
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" required="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btn-olvidado">
      Continue
    </button>
    <p class="help-block">
      <a class="text-muted" href="#" id="acceso"><small>Account Access</small></a>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#form-olvidado').show()">Forgot password?</a>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8cjrj118/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/8cjrj118/6/)

```
$('#forgot').click(function(){


    $('#form-olvidado').css(
        "display","block"
    );
    $('#loginbox').css(
        "display","none"
    );

});
```

**OR**

```
$('#forgot').click(function(){


    $('#form-olvidado').show();
    $('#loginbox').hide();

});
```

1. Add forgot as id to anchor tag which says forgot password ?
   then add this code
2. Secondly two methods can be used one is using css display block or none in jquery or
3. Hide or show both does the trick
4. Another thing regarding using jsfiddle In left side menu there is a tab called external resources you have to add css and other javascript files in that menu 
   [Go to this site](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)  it has all bootstrap and other files hosted so that it can be used on the fly